# Проблемы с подключением Oracle DB через JDBC, (SQLException)

Tags: база-данных, oracle, java-ee, tomcat, jdbc

Делаю проект на технологии JSP, в качестве сервера выступает Tomcat 7.0, бд - Oracle 10g XE.

БД установлена, запущена, настроена на порт 1521, пароль и логин соответствуют коду.

И так, при запуске проекта на сервер в логах томката видно следующее непотребство

```
мая 25, 2017 9:53:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable 
debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned 
but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can 
improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Exception in GetCon ((
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.javatpoint.MyListener.contextInitialized(MyListener.java:12)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5118)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5634)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
мая 25, 2017 9:53:36 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [2,338] milliseconds.
```

Видно что дело в MyListener,12 строка:

```
package com.javatpoint;
import javax.servlet.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class MyListener implements ServletContextListener{

public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    int status=0;
    Connection con=null;
try{
    con=GetCon.getCon();
    PreparedStatement ps1=con.prepareStatement("Select * from NEWCUST4");
    try{
    status=ps1.executeUpdate();
    }catch(Exception e)
    {e.printStackTrace();
     status=2;
     System.out.println("my staus is1111111"+status);
     }      

    if(status==0)
    {System.out.println("your table name already exist"+status);}
    else if(status==2) 
    {System.out.println("else if part table does not exist new table has created"+status);
    PreparedStatement ps3=con.prepareStatement("CREATE SEQUENCE javatpoint1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 NOCACHE  NOORDER  NOCYCLE");
    ps3.executeUpdate();

    PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE  NEWCUST4(ID NUMBER,USERNAME VARCHAR2(4000),PASSWORD VARCHAR2(4000), REPASSWORD VARCHAR2(4000),DISNAME VARCHAR2(4000), ADDERESS VARCHAR2(4000),CITYNAME VARCHAR2(4000),STATENAME VARCHAR2(4000),COUNTRY VARCHAR2(4000),REGION VARCHAR2(4000),PHONE NUMBER,EMAIL VARCHAR2(4000),PRIMARY KEY (ID))");
    ps.executeUpdate();

    PreparedStatement ps2=con.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE  NEWORDER4(ID NUMBER,PRODCODE VARCHAR2(4000),PRODUCTNAME VARCHAR2(4000),TAX NUMBER,MINQ NUMBER,ORDERQ NUMBER,DISCOUNT NUMBER,NETCOST NUMBER,AMOUNT NUMBER,PAYMODE VARCHAR2(4000),PRIMARY KEY (ID))");
    ps2.executeUpdate();

    PreparedStatement ps4=con.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE  PHARMACYADMIN(USERNAME VARCHAR2(4000),PASSWORD VARCHAR2(4000))");
    ps4.executeUpdate();
    ps4 = con.prepareStatement("Insert into PHARMACYADMIN values(?,?)");
    ps4.setString(1,"admin");
    ps4.setString(2,"admin");

    ps4.executeUpdate();

    PreparedStatement ps5=con.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE  DISTRIBUTERADMIN(USERNAME VARCHAR2(4000),PASSWORD VARCHAR2(4000))");
    ps5.executeUpdate();

    ps5 = con.prepareStatement("Insert into DISTRIBUTERADMIN values(?,?)");
    ps5.setString(1,"dis");
    ps5.setString(2,"dis");
    ps5.executeUpdate();

    }


    else{System.out.println("else part "+status);
    }}
    catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    System.out.println("project undeployed");

}
```

}

Понтяно что дело в вызове метода : con=GetCon.getCon();
А вот и он, источник всех бед и SQL Exception c логом "Exception in GetCon (("

```
package com.javatpoint;
import java.sql.*;
public class GetCon {
private GetCon(){}

 public static Connection con;
static{
try {
    Class.forName(DBIntializer.DRIVER);
    con=DriverManager.getConnection(DBIntializer.CON_STRING,DBIntializer.USERNAME,DBIntializer.PASSWORD);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SQLException e) {

    System.out.println("Exception in GetCon ((");
}
```

}

```
public static Connection getCon(){
return con;
}



public static int getPrimaryKey(){
int nextvalue=0;
Connection con=GetCon.getCon();
PreparedStatement ps2;
try {

ps2=con.prepareStatement("select javatpoint1.nextval from dual");

ResultSet rs=ps2.executeQuery();
rs.next();
nextvalue=rs.getInt(1);



} catch (SQLException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}
return nextvalue;

}
}
```

Данные для коннекта берутся из интерфейса DBIntializer, вот он:

```
package com.javatpoint;

public interface DBIntializer {
String DRIVER="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
String CON_STRING="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";
String USERNAME="system";
String PASSWORD="oracle";
}
```

Как все это дело фиксить?

Comment: метод e.getMessage() выдал такую инфу: Exception in GetConORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-12705: Cannot access NLS data files or invalid environment specified

Answer (score 0):

Нагуглил решение: нужно было просто добавить 
     Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);